# Automatically setting model attribute in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to populate a object as model attribute for each new request to my spring container.

I did the following.
-Added a new Interceptor within which am adding the object to request object 
-Registered the interceptor

The interceptor is getting executed but the controller is returning a employee object with all values as null. Am i doing something wrong?

```
public class UserDetailsInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {

    private static Class<? extends Annotation> annotationName = PopulateUserDetails.class;

    public UserDetailsInterceptor() {
        super(annotationName);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HandlerMethod handlerMethod)
            throws Exception {
        log.error("running my interceptor handle now");
        Employee empoyee = populateEmployeeDetails();
        request.setAttribute("employee",employee"); 
        return true;
    }

}


@Slf4j
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/tst1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @PopulateEmployee
    public Employee getEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee) {
        return employee;
    }

}
```

Comment: Request attributes are not model attributes and model attributes are not request attributes. When Spring MVC tries to render a view, it will transfer model attributes to request attributes.

Comment: How can i populate model attribute ?I want to add some model  attribute from interceptor

Comment: Why not to invoke `populateEmployeeDetails()` right in controller's method?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using AbstractInterceptor use HandlerInterceptorAdapter

UserDetailsInterceptor will be like this

```
public class UserDetailsInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter
{
    Employee empoyee = null;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        log.error("running my interceptor handle now");
        empoyee = populateEmployeeDetails();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        request.setAttribute("employee",employee"); 

    }
}
```